# Ask for calculating area under vector of rectangular pulse

Tags: matlab, area, pulse

I have a vector of time series data which each element represents the X(t) value. I would like to calculate the area under the curve of the vector data (the curve is represented in rectangular pulse form).

For example, X = [0 2 2 2 0 1 1 1 0];
Each element of the data is 1 second interval. After plotting the curve, its area should be 6 units.

How would I like Matlab code to calculate for this work? (I found that trapz() can do but using trapezoidal form (not rectangular pulse), so its output is larger)

Thank you.
Bundit

Comment: For your example, the area is 9 units right ?

Comment: The input is 9 elements and the output area is 6 (square-unit).

Comment: I have reached the solution for this problem. It is just to sum up all elements in the vector. The sum result is the area under the curve since the interval between elements is 1, each element value represents the area of a small rectangle (heigth X 1). The sum area of all rectangles is also the area of the curve under the vector data. Thanks for comment.